# Есть ли способ добавить кнопку 'Comments' под сообщением бота?

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram, бот

Я разрабатываю ботa для Telegram. Нужно прикрепить кнопку комментария под каждым ответом.

Возможно ли добавлять кнопку 'Comments' под каждым сообщением, которое поступает от бота? Если да, то каким образом это можно сделать?

[image: Вот пример такой кнопки, только меня интересует не канал или группа, а бот]

Comment: Hello, this is the site of the Russian-speaking community SO. please or translate your question into Russian.

Comment: Используйте inline кнопки.

Comment: @kotleni все равно не понимаю, каким образом, я могу кидать ссылку на коментарии? как создать эти комментарии?

Comment: @RuslanKovalenko, Добавьте просто ссылку на чат в Inline кнопку. Ну или изобретайте свое решение. Можно так же расположиться где-то на форуме.

Comment: @kotleni наверное я не совсем правильно описал проблему: мне нужны устроены комментарии в телеграмме, сейчас обновлю вопрос!

Comment: @RuslanKovalenko, вот теперь ясно. Этот 'бар' можно добавить только к сообщениям в канале.

Comment: @kotline Я думаю, вы также подсказали мне очень полезную штуку с этими ссылками в inline кнопками. Если бы был технический путь создания таких чатов - я бы мог добавлять в инлайн кнопки ссылки.

Comment: @RuslanKovalenko, технический путь создания таких чатов? Что вы имеете в виду?

Answer (score 0):

**Ответ:** нет.

*Этот 'бар' для перехода в обсуждение поста - доступен только в каналах.*